# How to link apache tomcat 7 and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, tomcat

I can't find a way to link apache tomcat and postgresql. I tried following [this link from apache documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). But I can't figure out where to put what with file, folder

Everything is a blunder, please help.

Comment: Did you find [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#PostgreSQL) while googling? If yes, where it failed?

Comment: *having issues* or "*didn't work much*" are neither valid Tomcat nor valid PostgreSQL error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's possible.  Maybe you should re-install Google: It surely can find things that will help you.

Start with a [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/).  That'll sort out connecting to PostgreSQL.

Next you'll need how to create a web app and deploy it on Tomcat.  Look at [First Web App](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/).  While you're there, see about JNDI data sources.

Do you know [how to write a servlet](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/)?  Learn that.

Those are the pieces you'll need.  UI is another matter, but this will show you the server side.  Good luck.

Comment: "*re-install Google*" - you made my day ;)